# Multicell simulation with omnetpp

Tags: omnet++

When I want to run the simulation Multicell (SimuLTE) I get the following error message:

> Error in module (VoIPSender) MultiCell.server.udpApp[0] (id=32) during network initialization: L3AddressResolver: address `ue11' not configured (yet?).

I think that the problem is in the air quote but I don't know how to fix that and because I'm working on Windows 10 its an illegal character, but i can't find where to change that. Can you tell me please how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simuLTE Multicell simulation with omnetpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122945/simulte-multicell-simulation-with-omnetpp)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a compatibility issue with INET and Windows.
You can use OmNet++ 4.4.1, INET 2.3 and SimuLTE revision from Oct 27, 2016.

Best regards,

Miguel Olmos